# Plot x to y, when x2 is equal to a specific value in R

Tags: r, plot

How do I do the above? I would like to plot the points for that, but I only know how to plot one variable to another, not considering any other variable.
First, I plot `x` to `y` and then I want I line (or points would be alright aswell) where `x2` is equal to a specific value.

example:

> x1: 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2 
>   x2: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 
>   y:  3,8,11,14,19,5,10,12,16,19

I want to plot x1 to y (x1 on x-axis, y on y-axis). That is

> plot(x1,y)

now I could plot the points I want to have like this:

> points(1,3)
>   points(2,19)

as these are the ones for x2==1.
But as I have a lot more data, I cannot do that. Plus I would like that to be a line.

Comment: Please provide an example of your graph code.  Also how are x and x2 related?

Comment: Please explain and provide an example of what the graph would look like.  As it stands, there's no way to tell what you're using the `x2` values for: to plot, or to select subsets of `x`, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following commands to generate the plot:

```
plot(x1, y)
points(x2, y)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
plot(x1, y, xlim = range(c(x1, x2)))
points(x2, y, col = "red", pch = 2)
```

[image]

By the way, `k++` does not work in R, use `k <- k + 1` instead.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I meant. This just gives me a vertical line at a specific x value.

Comment: @cups What is `x2` and what kind of line are you looking for?

Comment: No, sorry, I tried to specify it in the main question again. I want to have the y values for all x1's at a specific value of x2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to plot y vs. x1, but only for values of y and x1 for which x2 equals 1. The easiest way to do that is to combine the vectors into a data frame and use 'subset':

```
df <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)
dfSubs <- subset(df, x2==1)
```

And then plot it however you like, for instance:

```
plot(dfSubs$x1, dfSubs$y, type="l")
```

[image]